# Why Jade template engine adds brackets around data fields

Tags: node.js, pug

I have some data which comes from mongodb database (monk component)

If i run this jade template, it gives me brackets (<> around data)

```
  td: #{myitem.myfield}
```

If i type this, it works fine:

```
  td= myitem.myfield
```

I do not understand why jade puts brackets in the first case. I want to put 2 fields in the same td, so i do not know how to do...

```
 td: #{myitem.myfield} #{myitem.field2}
```

Answer (score 0):

`td:` is meant to nest tags (I think that it will *always* expand the first argument to a tag).

If you want two fields in the same `<td>`, you can just use this:

```
td #{myitem.myfield} #{myitem.field2}
```